# initialize module instance variable

Tags: ruby

I can't understand why my code doesn't work.

```
class Container
  module Actions 
    @instance_variable = 0;
    def action1
      return @instance_variable # no error, but doesn't return 0! What can be done ?
    end
  end
  include Actions
end

Container.new.action1()
```

I have a feeling there is a simple answer to it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ok, why the downvotes ? Coming from a Java environment one would expect that the instance variables get initialized when in internal 'classes' sort of. And information as to why this is not happening is quite hard to find.

Comment: In Ruby everything (literally) is an object so what you did is you initialised `class instance variable`. What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place it inside an initializer function:

```
class Container
  module Actions 
    def initialize
      @instance_variable = 0;
    end
    def action1
      return @instance_variable # no error, but doesn't return 0! What can be done ?
    end
  end
  include Actions
end

puts Container.new.action1().inspect  ## 0
```

Another less-proper way is to give default value if instance is not set:

```
class Container
  module Actions 
    def action1
      @instance_variable ||= 0
      return @instance_variable # no error, but doesn't return 0! What can be done ?
    end
  end
  include Actions
end
```

Comment: You nearly beat me to it, I was just about to post my own answer. But why doesn't it initialize my instance variables when the module is included ? I seem to be lacking some knowledge of the 'lifecycle' of the module

Comment: @victor check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25228488/2597260 .

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't initialize the instance variable? `puts Container::Actions.instance_variable_get(:@instance_variable) # 0`

Comment: Got it. It does initialize but not the way I expect it :). I would have expected to be able to use it inside the Container::Actions module without calling the getter

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because `@instance_variable` is instance of `Container::Actions` module object. Check it via `instance_variables`:

```
Container::Actions.instance_variables
# => [:@instance_variable]
```

It's the same as you define it in the class (not in the `initialize`):

```
class A
  @var = 42
end
A.instance_variables
# => [:@var]
```

So if you really wanted to use instance variable of `Container::Actions` you can use `instance_variable_get`:

```
class Container
  module Actions
    @instance_variable = 0;
      return Actions.instance_variable_get :@instance_variable
     end
   end
   include Actions
 end


 Container.new.action1()
```